# VBA filter working for calculations not for report launch

Tags: ms-access

I'm a beginner so please stick with me. I'm trying to make a user friendly form to calculate total cases for each worker during a date range, and to launch a report based off the same criteria. The calculation is working great but when I click the report it prompts me to enter the parameters for `SWNameFilter`. Thank you!

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub CalculateResultsSW_Click()
    Dim SWReport As DAO.Recordset
    Dim vChosenFilters As String
    If (Not IsNull(TestSWFromDateFilter)) And (Not IsNull(TestSWToDateFilter)) Then
    vChosenFilters = BuildFilterString
    CasesCount = DCount("[SPN]", "TestSW", vChosenFilters)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CloseForm_Click()
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    CalculateResultsSW_Click
End Sub

Private Function BuildFilterString()
    BuildFilterString = "(ArrestDate Between #" & TestSWFromDateFilter & "# And #" & TestSWToDateFilter & "#)"
    If Not IsNull(SWNameFilter) Then
        BuildFilterString = BuildFilterString & " And (SWName = " & "SWNameFilter" & ")"
        End If
End Function

Private Sub OpenSWReport_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.OpenReport "SWReport", acViewPreview, , BuildFilterString
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "SWReport", acFormatPDF, "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\PJDSW Report.pdf", True
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "SWReport"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you see the popup for `SWNameFilter` is that the query believes that it's a name parameter, and it's asking you to enter a value for that.

The reason for it is simple, this line:

```
BuildFilterString = BuildFilterString & " And (SWName = " & "SWNameFilter" & ")"
```

The problem is that you've surrounded your variable name with double-quotes, which basically treats it like text, so your query is becoming:

```
And (SWName = "SWNameFilter")
```

This is clearly incorrect, as what you actually wanted was to include the *value* of the variable:

```
BuildFilterString = BuildFilterString & " And (SWName = " & SWNameFilter & ")"
```

Note the removal of the double-quotes, which will then embed the value of the variable in to the SQL instead of the word `"SWNameFilter"`.

If `SWNameFilter` is a string (which I assume it is) then you'll want some double-quotes to be embedded into the SQL, which you can achieve like this in Access:

```
BuildFilterString = BuildFilterString & " And (SWName = """ & SWNameFilter & """)"
```

This will output:

```
And (SWName = "Value of SWNameFilter")
```

Comment: The value of the variable are names in last, first format and I was getting syntax errors previously which I thought was fixed by the quotes. Is there another way around this?

Comment: As I've mentioned in the answer, you need to embed double-quotes into the SQL string, which I've shown you how to do.  Copy and paste the code I posted and it will do what you're looking for

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! I appreciate your insight I've been staring at it all day.

Comment: @JordanG3 No problem, glad to have helped. Please remember to mark the answer as correct when you have a moment.

Comment: It is generally much easier to use single quotes for quotes that are meant to be part of a VBA-generated SQL statement (all SQL actually) rather than double-double quotes. That way it is much easier to see which quotes are for VBA and which are for SQL and the code is a lot more readable. The parenthesis is also superfluous. Specifically that would make it `BuildFilterString = BuildFilterString & " AND SWName='" & SWNameFilter & "'"`